# Google Analytics Unique Visitors by DAY doesn't match by WEEK

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics, analytics

When I'm checking unique visitors per DAY I see the following pretty-steady graph:
[image]
However, when I change the time-span to WEEK, I see this hugh drop:
[image]
Same thing happens when evaluating the exported CSV files. The SUM(7days) just doesn't add up to WEEK values. How can this be?

Comment: I can't explain the drop vs. the consistent daily, but as for the SUM(7days) : Since some countries have week start as Sunday and others Monday, maybe your SUM is starting on a different day (either Sunday/Monday) to the weekly aggregation Google is doing?

Comment: Can you check of u see similar weird stats under unique visitors graph in these time periods? (Compare time span day to week)

Answer (score 1):

can you check the selected date range?

**I would make sure that the date-range selected has the same days as starting and ending days.**

For example: If you are looking at July - August data, it would make sense to pick those two for example:

- Jul 7, 2013
- Aug 24, 2013

You end up with full 7 weeks (Sunday to Saturday) and then the chart should (provided there are no peaks/drops in traffic) show display a straight line:

[image]

Hope this helps!
Petr

Comment: Tried this, but still seeing the same issue. This only happens when I look at unique visitors. Is there any chance Google calculates 'unique' different according to the time span selected??

Comment: Noam, I think the issue might be in the logic that GA Applies. If you use the Unique Visitors sliced by date, you can end up with different numbers in total (let's assume you have returning visitors, so most of them would be listed as unique visitors for particular day, hence duplicated when calculating the week totals). I hope my answer makes sense :) It's a tricky issue... but GA is not (at the moment) the best tool to track visitors and some metrics and logic behind them is more complicated than it seems.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is explained by Avinash over here:
http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/standard-metrics-revisited-6-daily-weekly-monthly-unique-visitors/

If the same user comes back every day, he is counted in each of the daily views (total of 7 for the week). But when you switch to a weekly view, those same seven daily visits only count as one unique visit on a weekly basis. Thus, your overall numbers look less impressive as you expand the time tracking period.